# Physical Force Generation- Applications, weaknesses, and the science behind it

Tags: physics, super-powers, energy, combat, urban-fantasy

I've been developing this anti-hero, "Vicious," for a few weeks now- but I need some help concerning the specifics. Vicious has an ability known as "physical force generation." From any point on her body she can generate physical force. Vicious is holding a baseball in the palm of her hand. Through some pseudoscience nonsense that I haven't quite developed yet, the baseball is propelled into the air at 150 mph (241 km). This is the most basic application of her power, and the simplest method of propulsion for her.

In combat scenarios, Vicious can put an enormous amount of force behind attacks with her arms and legs. Brick, steel, and concrete either shatter or bend from her blows. Vicious can run at 70 mph (112 km) via generating moderate amounts of force from her soles. This is the fastest speed at which she can run before she loses the delicate control she has of her force output, and damages her surroundings (or throws herself up into the air- not entirely sure on this one). She can also jump large distances via pushing off of hard surfaces.

(Sidenote: this character has her limits. She is outfitted with metal bracers (essentially armor) that provides moderate protection for her legs and arms. If she goes beyond her limits, these bracers fall to pieces and she injures herself. She has a moderate healing ability that handles sprains, dislocations, and broken bones in a few days (but this is not ideal in a combat situation).)

Now that I have this power explained, how can I explain this power using comic book-y pseudoscience? What are some other applications of this power? Thank you!

EDITED to fit standards.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Worldbuilding. Please limit your post to **one** question, as it is currently too broad and might be closed. See the [help center](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) for more information on [how to write good questions](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. You are asking too many questions in a single post. By visiting the [help] and taking the [tour], you will see here we prefer to focus on one well defined and objectively answerable problem at a time.

Comment: I'd just like to point out that you don't need to explain the pure physics behind your character and you can work it out later. However you need to be consistent. If she can punch fast enough to set things on sure, then so can other people who move that fast can also do it (Unless its her power). The bracers don't make too much sense to me(costume or enhancers maybe?). She can already shatter steel, so usually you would also give her super durability alone with super strength, otherwise her bones will be crushed by her muscles tensing...

Comment: So basically she has All For One like in Boku no hero Acedemia?

Comment: As a suggestion, think of the Incredibles. You have supers, thats it. You don't need an explanation to have a good character and story. As long as you don't delve into it, your readers will also be okay with it. Like, think of the Mind control tech via spinning circles. Doesn't make sense physically, but you can make it work by focusing on the consequences and actions rather than the implementatino

Comment: One for All* Mixed them up cause I haven't watched it yet

Comment: I think instead of asking for "somewhat" of an explanation using "comic book-y pseudoscience" which just means: Make up a word, you should consider just asking straght up how this could be explained. Btw, could you exclude nanites? You can almost always just say "nanites" that live in her skin and can do all sorts of things, but that's super lame

Comment: I do love BNHA, but the power is purely force-based. There is no super strength involved, but to an onlooker it might appear that way. This superpower enables one to "force" a car away (propelled away), but does not grant the ability to lift said car using physical strength.

Comment: So I have a question, she's effected by the equal and opposite reaction of the force she emits?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by equal and opposite reaction? I had planned for a bit of a "recoil," in that when forcing something away she might be shot off in the opposite direction.

Comment: @Fortuna Usually if you apply a force, it pushes back at you just as hard as you are pushing it. So if you were on ice and punched a wall, your also going to slide back a little. When she applies her force power, does it also act on her? If so, you would basically need to consider the same downsides of super strength (although you could probably ignore the super bulky muscles)

Comment: Equal and opposite reaction means that if you push something, it pushes you back. Like pushing off against a wall; even though you push the wall, it pushes you backwards. So essentially recoil. Does the recoil act against her the same way it acts against the object, or against her entire body as a whole? IE does 'forcing' the baseball move just her arm, or her whole body?

Comment: Thanks for editing the question. Mind that you are still asking two different questions: how to explain the power, and how to use it. The last one being strongly opinion based, I think.

Comment: @ClayDeitas How is this an issue if you can just magically generate whatever "force" you like? You can always make it "her whole body"

Comment: @Randitz_35 Because if there's recoil and you use your force to launch a car, you're essentially being hit by a car. If your whole body absorbs the impact, you may rupture organs or something, but if only the hand touching the car recoils, your arm may explode.

Comment: @ClayDeitas this is not an issue because "any point" - unless I'm missing something. Just produce more force

Comment: @Raditz_35 The force produces recoil, so just adding more force will also hurt her.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Worldbuilding. A general writer's tip for you: think Chekhov's Gun... if you bring something into the narrative, **you must use it**. Bringing needless fluff into a narrative does not help you. Everything you put into writing should be there for a purpose, be it to be used as plot hooks, bringing flavour to the setting, lampshade hanging to help suspension of disbelief along... there must be **purpose** to that which you bring into the narrative. So unless you have intended to use the mechanics behind this superpower for something, then don't... just leave it out. :-)